# Can I calculate a fractional sum with functional equations and/or infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, functional-equations, summation-method

I was wondering if I can calculate fractional sums (non-integer sums) with functional equations in the following manner

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^xg(n)$$

> $$f(x)=g(x)+f(x-1)\tag1$$

$(1)$ most certainly should be true, and in using such an equation, I've seen fractional summations calculated.  (being wary that an extra constant will sneak in)

For instance,

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1n$$

$$\implies f(x)=\frac1x+f(x-1)$$

$$\implies \int_1^xf(t)dt=\int_1^x\frac1t+f(t-1)dt$$

$$\int_1^xf(t)dt=\ln(x)+\int_1^xf(t-1)dt$$

$$\implies\int_1^xf(t)-Cdt=\sum_{n=1}^x\ln(x)\tag{backwards $(1)$}$$

$$\implies\int_1^xf(t)-Cdt=\ln(\Gamma(x+1))$$

$$\implies f(x)=C+\frac{d}{dx}\ln(\Gamma(x+1))$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1n=\gamma+\frac{d}{dx}\ln(\Gamma(x+1))$$

where we find $C$ by putting in a trivial value, like $x=1$.

So... I was wondering if this is a possibly good way to going about fractional sums?

**EDIT**

I also find that defining a summation this way allows me to differentiate in a neat way:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^xg(n)=C+\sum_{n=1}^xg'(n)?$$

Is that correct?  Despite being a discrete type of thing, we simply assume it can be continuous and make sense of differentiating it?

It appears to pass well for easy/known sums that have closed forms and closed form derivatives.

---

Then my second thought.

Suppose we have a different approach utilizing infinite series:

$$p(x,k):=\sum_{n=k}^xq(n)$$

$$P:=\lim_{(x,k)\to(\infty,-\infty)}p(x,k)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q(n)$$

Let $P$ be some constant.

Since we can calculate $P$ through various methods, and numerically by adding terms, we could then manipulate things as follows,

$$p(x,k)=P-p(\infty,k)-p(x,-\infty)$$

And we can surely calculate $p(\infty,k)$ or $p(x,-\infty)$ by starting at $k$ or $x$, respectively, and approach $\infty$ term by term?

$$p(\infty,k)=q(k)+q(k+1)+q(k+2)+\dots$$

$$p(x,-\infty)=q(x)+q(x-1)+q(x-2)+\dots$$

Right?  So long as $P$ is actually a finite constant and the summation doesn't diverge, we can numerically approach the problem this way?

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. Have you tried the second approach with some examples?

Comment: @YuriyS well... no.  Thanks for the thought though, something I will see putting to mind.  The truth is I don't know many simple examples for the second approach.

Comment: @YuriyS That might hold for $x-k\in\mathbb N$, but it doesn't make sense for $x\in\mathbb N$, as $\lfloor x\rfloor=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb N$.  Also, try \$\lfloor x \rfloor\$

Comment: I can't really understand how are you 'starting with $x$' in your method. If $x$ is not an integer, that gets us back to the original problem. $$ ---$$ P.S. I deleted my latest comment for the same reason

Comment: @YuriyS In the last line?  Hm, I think I get what you mean.  I'll go and fix that.

Comment: @YuriyS I was thinking that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\dots f(-2)+f(-1)+f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+\dots$$ but thinking a little differently, perhaps we could also have $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\dots f(-1.5)+f(-0.5)+f(0.5)+f(1.5)+\dots$$and manipulate that, if they were equal.  But just an idea, I have plenty reason to understand it is probably wrong.  Maybe more correctly: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n+a)=\sum_{n=-\infty+a}^{\infty+a}f(n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n)$$

Comment: This is wrong indeed. You evaluate you function at a different set of points. For a general function the result would be different

Comment: @YuriyS Hm, ok.  I was just wondering how reindexing a function/summation works with infinite upper and lower limits.  I mean, it'd work fine with integrals, but those are continuous, unlike summations?