# Question on $\Pi_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^a}{\pi^an^a}\right)$ and the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

Question on what is

$$\Pi_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^a}{\pi^an^a}\right)$$

I deduced that for any $a=2,4,6,\dots$, the above product is simplify-able into a product of sines,

$$\Pi_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}x$$

$$\Pi_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^4}{\pi^2n^2}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)\sin(xi)}{x^2}$$

And trying to put this into a general form, I got

$$f(x):=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

$$\implies f(x)=f(-x)$$

$$f(x)f(ix)=\Pi_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^4}{\pi^4n^4}\right)=\sqrt{f(xe^{\frac{\pi i}{2}})f(xe^{\pi i})f(xe^{\frac{3\pi i}{2}})f(xe^{2\pi i})}$$

Using $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, we can get something along the lines of

$$\Pi_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^{2^a}}{\pi^{2^a}n^{2^a}}\right)=\sqrt{f(xe^{\frac{1\pi i}{2^a}})f(xe^{\frac{2\pi i}{2^a}})\dots f(xe^{\frac{2^a\pi i}{2^a}})}=\Pi_{n=1}^{2^a}\sqrt{f(xe^{\frac{n\pi i}{2^a}})}$$

> $$\implies\Pi_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^a}{\pi^an^a}\right)=\Pi_{n=1}^a\sqrt{f(xe^{\frac{n\pi i}a})}$$

I was wondering if this is correct and if it were possible to... take the Taylor Series of the RHS?  Specifically for $a=3$, as this would result in relations to the Riemann Zeta function.

Comment: Feel free to point out any errors I made along the way, as I likely made a mistake near the end.

Comment: You have $2^a$ magically changed to $a$. I mean, if you know something is true for any power of 2, it is not necessarily true for any integer.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yeah, I know, but at the least we know it works for any general multiple of 2, not just the powers of $2$, being that $f(x)$ is expandable and equal for $a=2$.  Related to why we have Riemann Zeta of positive even numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that for even $a$ you can write the infinite product as finite product over $\text{sinc}$ functions. This result does not extend to odd $a$ so your final equation is not true. I will here add a simple derivation of the identity for even $a$ and some notes about a related identity involving the $\Gamma$ function.

---

If $\omega$ is a $n$'th root of unity then $1 - z^{n} = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1 - z\omega^{k})$
since both sides of the equation are polynomials that agree at (the non-root) $z=0$ and have the same $n$ roots. Taking the product of this identity for $z = \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 m^2}$ over $m=1,2,3\ldots,N$ and then taking $N\to\infty$ we get

$$\prod_{m=0}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{x^{2n}}{\pi^{2n}m^{2n}}\right) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[ \prod_{m=0}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{x^2 e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}}{\pi^{2}m^2}\right)\right] = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \text{sinc}\left(e^{\frac{\pi i k}{n}}x\right)\tag{1}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The case you are interested in corresponds to $2n = 3$ or $n = \frac{3}{2}$ which is not covered by this derivation and neither does the identity above hold true for non-integer $n$.

There is a similar identity that allows for odd exponents in the infinite product, though involving more complicated functions, namely:

$$\prod_{m=0}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{x^{n}}{\pi^{n}m^{n}}\right) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{(-1)^ke^{\frac{\pi i k}{n}}x}{\pi}\right)}\tag{2}$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). When $n$ is even [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), $\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)} = \text{sinc}(z)$, can be applied to simplify the expression above into the form $(1)$ (combind the $k$'th term and the $2n-k$'th term in the product above). The disadvantage of this formula in the study of the infinite product is that the $\Gamma$ function for imaginary aguments is not very pleasant to work with.

Comment: How can you even graph it for $n=3/2$?  The product does not seem to be defined for that, you can't multiply $3/2$ terms, right?

Comment: Hm, does $(2)$ result in the relation between the Riemann Zeta function and the Gamma function?  (Something I haven't been able to fully look into yet)

Comment: @SimpleArt That is a very good point and a blunder. on my side I naively plotted it without thinking. $n$ evaluates to $1$ when doing so. I'll remove that part, thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if it were possible to calculate the product like a fractional sum, aka a sum that doesn't have upper and lower bounds that allow term by term calculations.  My thoughts(?): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844282/can-i-calculate-a-fractional-sum-with-functional-equations-and-or-infinite-serie

Comment: @SimpleArt I don't see the relation between the infinite product and the $\zeta$-function for $a=3$ you talk about. Can you elaborate?

Comment: $$g(x)=\ln(\Gamma(x))$$ $$g^{(n)}(1)=(-1)^n\zeta(n)$$ where $\zeta(1)=\gamma$.  I've just always been wondering why this is, since its come up in my works.

Comment: @SimpleArt What is $g(x)$ here? And where does $a=3$ come into play? To clarify what I mean; you mention in the post "Specifically for $a=3$, as this would result in relations to the Riemann Zeta function", what are you talking about here?

Comment: I was thinking that if $(2)$ were true, then we should be able to Taylor Series expand it, and the coefficient in front of $x^a$ for any $a$ would be $\frac{\zeta(a)}{\pi^a}$, but then this would mean the closed form of $\zeta(3)$ is already known, unless the 3rd derivitve of the LHS has no closed form in any other functions... $(1)$ may be Taylor expanded to produce all even values of $\zeta(a)$ by equating parts in this manner

Comment: Unless you can take the third derivative of that product of yours (where $a=3$), and multiply by $6\pi^3$ to get $\zeta(3)$ in closed form?

Comment: @SimpleArt If you series expand the right hand side of $(2)$ to $O(x^3)$ and compare to the left hand side you are just going to get the $\zeta(3) = \zeta(3)$, i.e. $1+1/2^3+\ldots = 1+1/2^3+\ldots$. Also there is highly likely no simple "closed form" for $\zeta(3)$ to be found, just expressions of it in terms of infinite series / products.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the informative answer.  I think this fully satisfies my question

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are seeking the relationship of this general product to the Riemann Zeta, there is an easy way to show it:

$$P(a,x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^a}{\pi^a n^a} \right)$$

$$\ln P(a,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \left(1-\frac{x^a}{\pi^a n^a} \right)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{ak}}{k~\pi^{ak} n^{ak}}$$

Note that $|x| \leq \pi$ for the latter series to converge. By the main definition of the zeta function, we have:

$$\ln P(a,x)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{ak}}{k~\pi^{ak}} \zeta (ak)$$